# Restate or withdraw a badly written bountied-question

Tags: discussion, bounty, low-quality-posts

I've been a member of this community for almost 9 years.
Recently, I've asked a question with a bounty - my first time!

Anyway, I've later realized that my question was badly written (just FYI, the link to the question is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237409/minimum-number-of-links-connecting-two-nodes-of-the-same-color)). Indeed, there are several omitted details, and a wrong statement of the problem. I believe that all these missing/wrong aspects concur to create confusion for the reader, and hence the quality of the answers is lowered accordingly.

Since it has been the first time for me, I'd like to know how to proceed now.

1. Should I remove the question and ask it again in a better way?
2. Should I edit the current question in order to improve it?
3. Should I do something else?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Having bountied the question, the rep you used as a bounty is lost.  Period.  You can not get a "return" on that.  I suggest you improve the question, but that gets tricky, as others may have already answered, based on the original question.  I suggest you consider this a learning experience.  If there are upvoted answers, you cannot delete the post.

Comment: In fact you have accepted an answer.  Your only choice now is how you choose to assign the bounty.  If you don't, you still lose the rep.

Comment: I am not sure that I really understand your question.  Generally speaking, we discourage users from making substantial edits to questions after they have been answered---such edits have the potential to invalidate the existing answers.  So I would think that editing your question is likely a bad idea.

Comment: On the other hand, once a question has an accepted answer, it cannot be deleted by the asker.  So option (1) is also not really a possibility.

Comment: Finally, I am not sure why the discussion of a bounty has been included.  What is the relevance of the bounty to the question you are asking here?

Comment: I have added two tags ([meta-tag:bounty]) and ([meta-tag:low-quality-posts]). The first one is relevant here, I was on the fence about the second one - so maybe somebody else can judge.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Are you sure of choosing [tag:bounty] in this post? I don't see any necessary of bounty point here just like Xander?

Comment: Look at the title, @Jitendra,  and  "I've asked a question with a bounty - my first time!"  While the OP fails to address why they felt that might change the outcome of their query, the fact is that askers of bountied questions are subject to the same policies as all questions are.

Comment: It is my understanding that in such a situation : 1. You have to eat the reputation loss (sorry) 2. Don't edit the Question to change what you are asking, as you will invalidate the current Answers 3. Post a new Question, linking to the old one if it helps.

Comment: Some information to keep in mind is that: 1. Deletion in most cases leads to refunding the bounty: [When a question that had bounties is deleted, are they automatically refunded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145329) 2. You cannot self-delete a questions which has an answer with an awarded bounty: [Changes to bounty rules: removal of double rep-retention, blocking of owner deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306966). (So the question you link can only be deleted by other users.)

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I'm considering to write a brand-new question.